# Create re-usable Generic lookup property with generic function

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I find myself often writing something like this, where foo is data intensive operation, that may or may not ever be called.

```
    private bool? _UseCapitalAssets;
    public bool UseCapitalAssets
    {
        get
        {
            if (_UseCapitalAssets == null)
            {
                return foo();
            }
            else
            {
                return _UseCapitalAssets.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Doing this allows me to re-use data if and only if I need it. How can I turn this into something more generic?

I'd like to write something like:

```
public class Lazy<T>
{
    private T _value;
    private bool lazySet = false;
    private Func<T> _method;


    public Lazy(Func<T> method)
    {
        _method = method;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (lazySet == false)
            {
                _value = _method();
                lazySet = true;
            }
            return _value;
        }
    }
}
```

which does compile, but when I try using it:

```
public Lazy<bool> UserLazy = new Lazy<bool>(fooMethod);
```

I get the compilation error: "cannot access non-static method 'fooMethod' in non-static context".

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Why are you writing your own `Lazy<T>` instead of using the one in the framework?

Comment: @Servy What Lazy in the framework are you talking about?

Comment: There's only one.  It's called `Lazy`.